# The best way to export 3d mesh animation in order to use it in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, graphics, 3d

Suppose that I have a 3d model with animation in, say, Blender. I need to export this model to some file and then use it in OpenGL app, i.e. without hardcoding animations, but reading them from file. What format is the best solution?

Comment: "3d mesh animation"...vertex?  skeletal?  "Best"?

Answer (score 1):

OpenGL doesn't support any format directly, but the classic OBJ file format lines up very well with drawing with vertex arrays. Basically, OBJ lists all vertices independently of the geometry. This way, several objects can share the same points. All kinds of groupings are also possible.

Also, it is one of the earliest formats to support a wide range of spline curves & surfaces, including Bezier, B-Splines & NURBS.

A basic decription can be found here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file

The complete OBJ spec can be found here:
http://www.martinreddy.net/gfx/3d/OBJ.spec

It's not as modern as WebGL, but it's simple, human readable and widely supported.

Answer (score 0):

> What format is the best solution?

OpenGL doesn't care about file formats. So feel free to choose whatever suits your needs best. Due to the rise of WebGL I started dumping whole Blender scenes into collections of JSON formated files.